# Dynamically Change object name

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have 7 Columns in datatables that are modified via callbacks.
Rather than hard coding each object name I want to do it dynamically

for example:

```
 {"data": "Times", "bSortable": false, "className": "col_odd",
            "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                var d = (data.hasOwnProperty('Mon') ? data.Mon.total_hrs : "");
                if(d === "null") d = "";

                var x = '<div class="text-center">' + d + '</div>';
                return x;

            }
        },
```

Instead I would like to do something like the following:

```
"render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                var day = "Mon";
                var d = (data.hasOwnProperty(day) ? data.[day].total_hrs : "");
                if(d == null) d = "00:00:00";

                var x = '<div class="text-center">' + d + '</div>';
                return x;

            }
```

But nothing I've tried works including the latter portion of code. How can I dynamically replace a part of an object reference?

Comment: `data[day]` instead of `data.[day]`. See [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)

Comment: Yeah, I had one `.` too many. Thanks